# Use of undeclared type

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to push a view controller from another storyboard onto the current view. I've created a function in my UIViewController subclass (NewsViewController):

```
func clickedOnNews() {
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(UIStoryboard(name:"Folders", 
bundle: Bundle.init(for: NewsViewController.self))
.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "addToFolderViewController") as! AddFolderViewController, animated: true)
}
```

}

The error is "Use of undeclared type 'AddFolderViewController'". I have imported Folders since AddFolderViewController is in another module. Please advise.

Comment: Does it help if you change `addToFolderViewController` to `addFolderViewController` ?

Comment: addToFolderViewController is the storyboardID

Comment: Just remove the  `as! AddFolderViewController` and add the `completion: nil` parameter to the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. The class AddFolderViewController needs to be set to public, I think because its in another module? Thanks everyone.